# Overlay 2 bitmaps of different sizes, into one the size of the screen

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, overlay, scale

I have 2 bitmaps, one is: width 720 x 404 height. the other is 1280x550
I used this function:

```
public Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Bitmap bmp2new = getResizedBitmap(bmp2, bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getWidth(), bmp2.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2new, 0, 0, null);
    return bmOverlay;
    }
```

Now it shows me both. overlayed. Now the first one, is a screen capture from a video, and the second is the canvas i draw on. The problem is that if i draw something on something thats on the margin of the screen, it will be overlayed incorrectly (an offset) because, my video is stretched to be the same as the seconc picture.
What can i do, to put both pictures, but the screen capture to start with an offset of a couple of pixels, so it will be correctly placed?

I tried:

```
  int left = (int)((bmp2.getWidth() - (bmp1.getWidth()*(bmp2.getHeight()/bmp1.getHeight())))/2.0);
    Bitmap bmp1new = getResizedBitmap(bmp1, bmp2.getHeight(), ((bmp2.getWidth() - (bmp1.getWidth()*(bmp2.getHeight()/bmp1.getHeight())) , bmp1.getConfig());
  Bitmap bmptest = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1new, left, 0,bmp1new.getWidth() - left, bmp1new.getHeight());
```

But had no luck, and now I'm even more confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked with this:

```
   public Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp2.getWidth(), bmp2.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    float left =(bmp2.getWidth() - (bmp1.getWidth()*((float)bmp2.getHeight()/(float)bmp1.getHeight())))/(float)2.0;
    float bmp1newW = bmp1.getWidth()*((float)bmp2.getHeight()/(float)bmp1.getHeight());
    Bitmap bmp1new = getResizedBitmap(bmp1, bmp2.getHeight(), (int)bmp1newW , bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1new, left ,0 , null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
    return bmOverlay;
    }
```